# putting divs under each other and moving to next column when they reach the end of parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

im trying to create a category menu ... ithink i can explain what i want better with this image

[image]

so i want my categories to fall under each other until they reach the end of menu  div and then next category goes to the next col

i can do something by calculating  `menu div height` and `each category height`  like if menu div height is `200px` and each category height is `50px`

```
<div class="col-md-3">
@foreach($categories as $k=>$category ) 

{{$category->title}}

@if($k%4 == 0 )
</div><div class="col-md-3">
@endif


@endforeach
</div>
```

but i prefer a cleaner/natural way , ideally css/html only solution

btw col divs(col-md-3) are not necessary  ... i just want categories to fill the page in the way described in the picture

im using bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If i understand right then you can simply do this with CSS.

Check my code.

```css
.outer {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  place-content: flex-start;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  background: #cacaca;
  margin: 3px;
  max-width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    <li>item4</li>
    <li>item5</li>
    <li>item6</li>
    <li>item7</li>
    <li>item8</li>
    <li>item9</li>
    <li>item10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: yep thats what i want , thanx im going to try it and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for this code seems fine.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
@foreach($categories as $k=>$category ) 

{{$category->title}}

@if($k%4 == 0 )
</div><div class="col-md-3">
@endif


@endforeach
</div>
```

But `$k` should start with `1` if it starts with `0` then you got an issue. because if
`if $k=0` than your `if` condition will be like this
`if(0%4 == 0)` so it will become true. and will get unexpected results.

So make sure where `$k` is starting.

Hope this will help you.